# REDCap auto populate from previous forms

Tags: database, redcap

Hi I am using REDCap for data collection. My question is how to auto populate variable from one from to another form in REDCap. For example, BMI from enrollment to baseline visit.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly how the piping will work will depend on your project design and setup. From your question it sounds as though you're running a longitudinal study. In a longitudinal study, an instrument exists within an event. You need to prepend the field variable name with the event name.

Say you had two events: Enrollment and Baseline, and in Enrollment you had two instruments: Consent and Medical History Questionnaire. In the Baseline event, you might have the Medical History Questionnaire again, plus event-specific forms, like a mood scale.

In REDCap, fields are globally unique among all *instruments*, and so usually you need to simply indicate the field using the [var] syntax. In a longitudinal study however, a single instrument can exist in multiple *events*, and to correctly identify the field, you need to first indicate the event name.

To pipe the BMI field (assuming it's labelled `[bmi]`) from the Enrollment event, you would use the piping code `[enrollment][bmi]`.

If your instance has version 8.4 or above, you should have access to smart variables. These allow you to traverse the events in a dynamic way using variables like `[previous-event]`, `[first-event]`, etc. You can use this to perform advanced branching logic to display some text on a form only if that form is not in the first event of a longitudinal study: `[event-name] != [first-event-name]`

Answer (score 0):

It's called piping in REDCap. you simply put the variable inside brackets and use it as a parameter on any forms.
This link has the piping example in it.
http://www.ecu.edu/cs-itcs/redcap/upload/REDCap-Advanced-User-Guide.pdf

Comment: We're trying to build a body of valuable content, not only links. Can you improve your answer by giving some sample code please?